# Make fibo faster

Tags: python, fibonacci

I need to write a code to give a number and print me the F[number].This code is pretty slow.Any ideas for a faster code?

```
 while True:
      n=input()
      if n=='END' or n=='end':
         break
      class Fibonacci:
            def fibo(self, n):
                if int(n) == 0:
                   return 0
                elif int(n) == 1:
                   return 1
                else:
                  return self.fibo(int(n)-1) + self.fibo(int(n)-2)
      f=Fibonacci()
      print(f.fibo(n))
```

Comment: Why `class`? that declaration is totally unnecessary..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have written a bit about faster fibonacci in this post, maybe one of them is useful for you?   https://sloperium.github.io/calculating-the-last-digits-of-large-fibonacci-numbers.html

Anyway. Your code is very slow because you get exponential running time calling the same subtrees over and over.

You can try a linear solution:

```
def fib3(n):
    if n == 0:
        return 0
    f1 = 0
    f2 = 1

    for i in range(n-1):
        f1,f2 = f2, f1+f2
    return f2
```

Comment: `n -= 1` is completely pointless; the `range` loop is using the original `n`. I'm guessing you started with a `while` loop based solution, changed to `for`, then didn't delete the `n-=1`.

Comment: you are very correct :-)

Answer (score 2):

You can use [functools memoize](https://wiki.python.org/moin/PythonDecoratorLibrary#Memoize) to make it store previous values so it doesn't have to recursively call the fibonacci function. The example they list is literally fibonacci

Answer (score 1):

You can use a dict to memoize the function:

```
class Fibonacci:
    memo = {}
    def fibo(self, n):
        if n in self.memo:
            return self.memo[n]
        if int(n) == 0:
            value = 0
        elif int(n) == 1:
            value = 1
        else:
            value = self.fibo(int(n) - 1) + self.fibo(int(n) - 2)
        self.memo[n] = value
        return value
```

Answer (score 1):

Use dynamic programming: this prevents it calculating all the way down to 0 and 1 each time:

```
memory = {0:0, 1:1}
def fibo(n):
    if n in memory:
        return memory[n]
    else:
        ans = fibo(int(n)-1) + fibo(int(n)-2)
        memory[n] = ans
        return ans
```

Test:

```
>>> fibo(1000)
43466557686937456435688527675040625802564660517371780402481729089536555417949051890403879840079255169295922593080322634775209689623239873322471161642996440906533187938298969649928516003704476137795166849228875
```

This is almost instantaneous.

Answer (score 1):

1. Don't use a `class`; you're not gaining anything from it
2. Don't needlessly redefine your class each loop
3. Convert from `str` to `int` once, up front, rather than over and over
4. (If not required by assignment) Use iterative solution, not recursive

With just #1-3, you'd end up with:

```
def fibo(n):   # Using plain function, defined once outside loop
    if n < 2:
        return n
    return fib(n - 1) + fibo(n - 2)

while True:
    n = input()
    if n.lower() == 'end':
        break
    print(fibo(int(n)))  # Convert to int only once
```

If you're not required to use a recursive solution, don't; Fibonacci generation is actually a pretty terrible use for recursion, so redefine the function to:

```
def fibo(n):
    a, b = 0, 1
    for i in range(n):
        a, b = b, a + b
    return a
```

which performs `O(n)` work rather than `O(2**n)` work. Memoizing could speed up the recursive solution (by decorating `fibo` with `@functools.lru_cache(maxsize=None)`), but it's hardly worth the trouble when the iterative solution is just so much faster and requires no cache in the first place.